# Why is IE mishandling the CSS auto margin here?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9

IE 7 and 9 are displaying #logon on the right hand side of #wrapper.

Live page is here: http://lalabs.hiv411.org/logout.php

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:960px;
    min-height:680px;
    background:url(../g/bg.jpg) no-repeat #6CB8D2;
    top:0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
}

#logon {
    position:relative;
    background:url(../g/login_bg.png) no-repeat;    
    width:656px;
    height:484px;
    margin: 135px auto;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

#logonInner {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 66px 0 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

HTML is dead simple...

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logon">
<div id="logonInner">
<img src="g/welcome.gif" alt="Welcome to the Louisiana Office of Public Health Survey of Laboratories and Facilities" name="welcome" width="397" height="110" id="welcome" />
<p>Please login using the username and password you were assigned.</p> 

 <form id="logonForm" method="post" action="">
     <label class="logonFormLabel"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>" class="required email logonFormText "/><br />
USER NAME</label>

     <label class="logonFormLabel"><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value="" class="required logonFormText"/><br />
PASSWORD</label>

<p style="padding:30px 0 0 0"><a href="lookup_facility.php" class="loginNav">Lookup Your Laboratory or Facility</a> <a href="request_login.php" class="loginNav">Request Login Information</a> <a href="forgot_password.php" class="loginNav">Forgot Your Password?</a></p>
<p style="padding:20px 0 0 0"><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></p> 
</form>
</div><!--logonInner-->
</div><!--logon-->
</div><!--wrapper-->
```

What's wrong with my CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added text-align:center to #wrapper.

Comment: If this solves your problem, then your page is working in quirks mode, which is a big no-no. The red light appears to be that HTML comment just above your doctype that contains some unattended PHP output. Perhaps you should investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `clear; both` after the Floated Elements and make sure... If you ever have a absolutely positioned element to have the parent element with the position of relative.

```
#parent {
   position: relative;}
#child {
   position: absolute;}
```

Then of course after you declare your floated elements, make sure you add a clear after them.

```
#element {
   clear: both;}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also for the #wrapper... Just do margin: 0 auto; .

Comment: Having trouble remembering why I had to use position absolute on wrapper but I am sure I did have to...

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: Well I see you fixed it. Hope I helped! :-D

Comment: I added text-align:center to #wrapper.  Thanks for the replies.